# Create a rolling code garage door opener

Tags: rf, raspberry-pi

I've been tinkering with my Raspberry Pi lately and I've been looking at opening garage doors. A majority of garage doors have the ability to "learn" a new remote. Is it possible to program a Pi with a 315MHz transmitter to "sync up" with a garage door receiver using the learn button?

I've been looking online and I haven't come across anything that can tell me what frequencies garage doors run on and what data the transmitter needs to send.

Long story short, I want to create a garage remote exclusively with the Pi and accessories.

Comment: Not unless you make the receiver too, perhaps with another Pi.

Comment: Restating what I said below, the algorithm isn't out there to mimic the signals of a garage door remote with a pi? How do car manufacturers do it with their built-in garage door opener remotes?

Comment: Exactly. If you make both ends you don't have to discover the commercial algorithm; you can roll your own. It won't keep your car safe from the NSA, but why would they want your car anyway?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you'd  need to know the code algorithm that the remotes are using. 
this is a usually trade secret of the door-opener manufacturer

I guess you could attach a 315MHz receiver to the pi and record a million codes from a remote and store them in a file.

you'd probably then be able to play back the codes and they would follow the mutation pattern that the door opener is expecting.

Comment: Figured as much. I setup a 315MHz receiver and a 433MHz receiver although neither could pick up any garage door remotes I had laying around(yes I'm sure they work). How can I tell what frequency they are using?

Comment: if careful inspection of the devices and their documnetation doesn't offer any clues I you're need some sort of scanner I guess.

Comment: @ssabetan Typical remotes are not always exactly on frequency so you might have to scan nearby frequencies.  A sensitive frequency counter 'may' be able to get the carrier freq if it keeps transmitting long enough.  Inspecting the frequency setting components (often SAW resonators or filters these days) you may be able to determine the centre frequency.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Modern garage door remote systems use proprietary/commercial rolling code encryption ICs, signed with a manufacturer's signature. If you do not know the signature, you cannot match the rolling code systems. The IC themselves are well documented.

> The Microchip HCS301 was once the most widely used system on garage and gate remote control and receivers. The chip uses the KeeLoq algorithm.

You would be unlikely to create a working remote for an existing system using just the RPI.

You could take a valid Remote/IC and control it from the RPI using some simple transistor control.

Comment: If they use a proprietary rolling code signed with the manufacturer's signature, how can third party controllers like the garage door opener in your vehicle "sync" up or learn/program with the controller? The RF remotes built into vehicles aren't created by garage door opener companies.

Comment: @ssabetan The receiver and transmitter chips were sold by the same vendor and had to be used in pairs.  The remotes were usually available from a couple of vendors and if they used the same chip and frequency then competitive products would be able to learn them as well.